# Unexpected behavior of ternary operator in C#

Tags: c#

```
static void test(bool b)
{
    int i = 1; char c = (char)65;
    string s; if (b) s = "blubb" + i; else s = "blubb" + c;
    string t = "blubb" + (b ? i : c);
    Console.WriteLine(s + " == " + t);
}
```

The call test(true)  gives "blubb1 == blubb1".

The call test(false) gives "blubbA == blubb65".

**Additional Question**

Edited:

```
static void test(bool b)
{
    int i = 1; char c = (char)65;
    string s; if (b) s = "blubb" + i; else s = "blubb" + c;
    string t = "blubb" + (b ? i : c);
    string u = "blubb" + (b ? c : i);
    Console.WriteLine(s + " == " + t + " == " + u);
}
```

The call test(true) gives "blubb1 == blubb1 == blubb65".

The call test(false) gives "blubbA == blubb65 == blubb1".

What explains this unexpected behavior?

Comment: You'll probably be better off writing one statement per line when coding - it'll make your life a lot easier to debug these kinds of things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

> `condition ? first_expression : second_expression`
>   ...
>   Either the type of *first_expression* and *second_expression* must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

As there is an explicit conversion between `char` and `int` (but only an explicit the other way around) the type of the following call

```
boolean ? integer : character
```

is `int`.

When you concatenate any non-string object with a string, `ToString()` is called on the object.

---

This means:

```
  "string" + integer
= "string" + integer.ToString()
```

and

```
  "string" + character
= "string" + character.ToString()
```

and finally

```
  "string" + (boolean ? integer : character)
= "string" + integerResult
= "string" + integerResult.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the key line

```
string t = "blubb" + (b ? i : c);
```

As `i` is of type `int` it casts `c` to an `int`.

The line before `string s; if (b) s = "blubb" + i; else s = "blubb" + c;` can be rewritten in a more readable way.

```
string s;
if(b)
{
    s = "blubb" + i; // i is an int here
    // So s = "blubb" + 1;
}
else
{
    s = "blubb" + c; // c is a char here. The char 'A'.
    // So s = "blubb" + 'A';
}
```

---

Two answer the second part of your question. `(b ? c : i)` is resolving to an `int` when you would expect to see a `char`.

This is because converting a `char` to an `int` is an implicit conversion.
Where as converting an `int` to a `char` is a explicit conversion.

In the ternary operator the implicit conversion is used.